# Allowing surrogate key repeat and record overwrite

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in my database where the primary key is a surrogate key (auto-incriminating identity). The table is insert and read only, and will be added to quite frequently. (it is more or a less a logging table).

When the PK reaches the max value of an int in SQL server, instead of going negative, or throwing an error, I just want it to return to 1, and overwrite the previous record which had 1 assigned as its primary key, and so on.

Is this possible to do with table settings (as opposed to logic in a sql query, or a trigger)?

My motivation behind this is keeping this table as low maintenance as possible.

Comment: Why not just change your datatype to bigint? Then even with thousands of inserts per second you have a few million years before you run out of numbers. And the part about overwrite....that makes no sense. Are you saying you want to update an existing row instead of insert?

Comment: @SeanLange the table will have a lot of indexes, I don't want to hinder them by using a larger key than I need, for data which I don't need to be permanently stored.

Comment: Why use that as a PK anyway, if it's going to later be reassigned?  Why not use truly unique fields for the key (timestamp + ?), then ditch the autoincrement column.  Use a view to display a rowcount or the most recent records.  This is a no-maintenance approach that doesn't require odd changes of data.  Lastly, if this truly is meant to be a write-only table, the overwriting data contradicts that purpose, so losing data from a permanent datastore might have unintended consequences.

Comment: @K_foxer9 the clustered index, which is by default the PK, is used by all the other indexes to refer to a specific record. as for insert only, fixed in edit

Comment: Your concern about the key is a bit confusing. Are you saying that every index will have the primary key in it?

Comment: @SeanLange in all SQL DBs that I know of, non-clustered indexes are implementing by listing the indexed column in order, and referring that particular value to the clustered index.

Comment: I gotcha, you are concerned about storage space then. I was misinterpreting what you were concerned about. Still not sure why you don't just go with bigint and be done with it forever. Or even forget using an identity entirely since you say this is a logging table. How often do you pull data from a logging table anyway?

Comment: a big int for a clustered index makes the various non-clustered indexes more intensive to maintain. And yes, I don't want eat up space as I know this table will have a lot of records. Up to several thousand inserts a second. As for reads, I do not know their frequency yet